# Creating virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a very simple question. According to this [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnbtI.png), I have created a virtualenv named *newConda* in this address `C:\Users\....\Envs`. So, my question is: how can I create this virtualenv in any other path of my choice, for example, in `E:\programming\New` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the advantages of `virtualenvwrapper` is that it stores all your virtual environments in one place so it can manage them at once.

If you want to create a virtual environment in another place you just use `virtualenv` instead of `virtualenvwrapper`.

If you want to store all your `virtualenvwrapper`'s virtual environments in a different directory define (change)  environment variable `WORKON_HOME`:

```
set WORKON_HOME=E:\programming\New
```

Comment: But then I have to use long commands to activate those environments, so is there a way, in which I can move the whole virtualenvwrapper folder to another directory.

Comment: I extended the answer.