# Python Virtual Environment Organization & Management

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I work on several projects and tech stacks and Python and ML is just one of them. I have an organization based on the domain that I'm working on. For example., all ML-Prpjects are organized in a folder like this:

```
/home/me/Projects/ml-projects/...
```

I'm just starting out with OpenCV and I just came across Python Virtual Environment Wrapper and I used the following script in my bashrc to set it up:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.local/bin/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=$HOME/.local/bin/virtualenv
source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

This leaves me with the virtual environment located in the .local folder. But how can I attach a virtual environment to my projects within my Project folder? I want my virtual environment folder physically located inside my Projects folder and not cluttered somewhere on the .local folder. Any clues?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584753/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873279/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Python includes a [`venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and you don't really need any wrapper if you just want to create the virtualenv in the current directory

```
python -m venv myvenv  # in any directory
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Should I source it everytime?

Comment: Yes, that's the command that activates the virtual environment. Although it's possible to write a shell script that automatically "sources" the file when you `cd` into the directory